# Can i sell my testnet tokens

Tags: tokens, testnets, bitcoin

I have some testnet tokens Eth,btc,litecoin,I need to know how can I sell this can we swap this to mainnet any site to do this

Comment: No, it's "certainly" not possible unless you do a kind of scam project to swap such as tokens between networks, which of course is not encouraged from this forum.

Answer (score 5):

You can sell them for my test dollars. I printed them with my inkjet printer just for you.

Comment: Ok then how to sale my testnet coins any site

Comment: Nobody wants your testnet tokens, they are worthless

Comment: Ok now I understand I need to know any site for testnet to exchange I need to exchange it to geodb testnet coin can you help

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can sell anything as long as some one buys it.
But testnet tokens are worthless. Maybe you can use them as some club point or something for your website (like coupons). so people don't have to pay Real ETH to send them back to you (transaction fees)